# SSRS: change font color based on the expression

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, colors

I am trying to give the below expression for font color in ssrs:

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0, IIF(Fields!A.Value >= Fields!P.Value, "Green", "Red"), "Black")
```

It works fine for all the numbers except when Either of A or P is 0 I am getting both A and P as Black.

Basically, All I want is:

1. When A = P = 0  Black
2. When A >= P (for eg. say both are 5) then Green
3. When A < P Red

The IIF syntax did not work as I expected i.e. When I have 0 in P and 5 in A then the font color should be green and the vice versa should be red.

I have to work a way around to get what I want with Switch statement.

```
=Switch(Fields!A.Value>=Fields!P.Value and (Fields!P.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0), "Green",
(Fields!A.Value = 0 and Fields!P.Value =0), "Black",
(Fields!A.Value=0 AND Fields!A.Value < Fields!P.Value), "Red",
(Fields!P.Value = 0 AND Fields!A.Value > Fields!P.Value), "Green")
```

Can someone explain to me why my IIF statement did not work please?

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: missed the 3rd one: when A<p then red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is

> My values are P = 0, A = 5, but colour is not green

(which I think it is)

Then this is because you are using the construct

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0 , truepart, falsepart)
```

You are saying that only do the true part when A is not zero **AND** P is not zero.  Because you are comparing the values 0 and 5, then because one of these is zero, the false part will execute instead.

To implement the rules

> 1. When A = P = 0 Black
> 2. When A >= P (for eg. say both are 5) then Green
> 3. When A < P Red

Then you will need an expression like

```
=iif(Fields!A.Value = 0 AND Fields!P.Value = 0, "Black",  <-- Set to Black if both zero
   iif(Fields!A.Value >= Fields!P.Value , "Green",        <-- Else, set to Green if A >= P
    "Red"))                                               <-- Otherwise set to Red
```

Hopefully this is helpful.  If I have misunderstood please let me know and I shall try to assist further

Comment: You are missing an `iif` in else part.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the reply. I will try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IIF` is not working because it is doing something else. To understand what it's doing, the equivalent `SWITCH` for that `IIF` is:

```
=Switch(Fields!A.Value>=Fields!P.Value and (Fields!P.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0), "Green",
NOT(Fields!A.Value>=Fields!P.Value and (Fields!P.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0)), "Black",
Fields!A.Value<>0 AND Fields!P.Value <>0 AND NOT(Fields!A.Value >= Fields!P.Value), "Red"
```

What you actually needed was:

```
IIF(
    Fields!P.Value=0 AND Fields!P.Value =0, 
    "Black",
    IIF(
        Fields!A.Value>=Fields!P.Value,
        "Green",
        "Red"
       )
   )
```